# Alterar versão Asp.Net Core

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

Instalei a versão 3.0 do Asp.Net Core em meu projeto, mas vou precisar alterar para uma anterior no caso a 2.2, tem alguma forma de fazer isso?[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2):

Primeiramente, você precisa ver se a versão desejada do .NET Core está instalada.
Para fazer isso, abra o prompt de comando (cmd) e digite:

```
dotnet --info
```

Aparecerão todas as versões do SDK no qual você tem instalado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Caso você não possua a versão desejada, você pode baixa-la [aqui](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core).

Após verificado que você possui a versão desejada, clique com o direito em seu projeto e selecione "Propriedades":

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Na aba Application, em "Target Framework", basta selecionar a versão desejada.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

**É possível alterar à partir do arquivo .csproj.**

Clique sobre o projeto com o botão direito, escolha Unload Project. Após o projeto ficar desabilitado com a descrição (unloaded), Clique novamente e escolha Edit Project File.

Localize a tag:

```xml
<TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.0</TargetFramework>
```

altere o valor para netcoreapp2.2

```xml
<TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.2</TargetFramework>
```

Salve as alterações, feche o arquivo, clique novamente sobre o projeto e escolha Reload Project. As dependências serão automaticamente restauradas para a versão desejada.

Esse método é valido também para outros tipos de projeto além do asp.net core, e permite por exemplo adicionar várias versões de saída, o que permitiria compilar tanto para 2.2 quanto 3.0.

Abaixo está a descrição de todas as versões:

https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/standard/frameworks#supported-target-frameworks

Answer (score 0):

Felipe, você pode instalar a outra versão que precisa ao lado da versão atual. Se o seu projeto não é executado na v3.0, então será executado na v2.2. Uma versão instalada não impacta no funcionamento da outra.

Segue o link para download: https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core